# MATLAB: Function not executing from script file

Tags: matlab

so i created a function

`function output = height (t)`

`output = (-9.8./2).*t.^2 + 125 *t + 500;`

`height (0:0.5:30)`

I saved the file in the matlab directory for where it's saved, and

Comment: Is this three lines saved in one file? In this case, last line will be part of function.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ Danil Asotsky thanks man exactly what the problem was, cheers to the others as well

Comment: To whoever has a related question, basically for the test. You create a new script file to generate your function, then save it and close it. It will be stored and ready to use in its functional form within your original script file with answers. Also Danil, i would really like to give you reputation but i seem to not know how to from the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in a single file `Editor`, `save` and 'run/launch':

```
function main()

 height(0:.1:30)

end


function out = height (t)

 out = (-9.8./2).*t.^2 + 125.*t + 500;  

end
```